# installing apache airflow using a custom nexus repo

Tags: airflow

I am trying to install apache-airflow (`pip install apache-airflow`) and I have to use a custom nexus to get it from. It is downloaded fine, but after the download it tries to run its `setup.py` which has got its dependencies to download, it tries to get its dependencies from `https://pypi.org/` which is blocked in my environment ( I cant use that). Is there a way to tell it to look for all its dependencies in my nexus rather than `https://pypi.org/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at https://packaging.python.org/guides/hosting-your-own-index/ to setup custom PyPI repository. Once that is setup, pip will use that to download dependencies.